# jena read inputstream from gzipped file

Tags: java, inputstream, jena

I have the following code to read a dataset into a jena model using inputstream however I would like my program to be able to read compressed (gzipped) files as well (using filePath).

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(tdbPath);
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
InputStream str = FileManager.get().open(filePath);
model.read(str,null, "N-TRIPLES");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a GZIPInputStream to read it then

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(tdbPath);
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
InputStream str = FileManager.get().open(filePath);
if (useGZIP) {
   str = new GZIPInputStream(str);
}
model.read(str,null, "N-TRIPLES");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the newer [`RDFDataMgr`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html) APIs then GZip compression should be handled entirely transparently:

```
RDFDataMgr.read(model, filePath, Lang.NTRIPLES);
```